A question in one step of proving Van Der Corput's Difference Theorem
In proving Van Der Corput's Difference Theorem, there's a lemma:
Suppose $\left\{ z_{n} \right\}$ is a bounded complex-valued sequence. Then if for all $d \in \mathbb{N}$ , we have \begin{align*}
\lim\limits_{N \to \infty } \frac{1}{N} \sum\limits_{n=1}^{N} z_{n+d} \overline{z_{n}} =0 
\end{align*}
then we have
\begin{align*}
\lim\limits_{N \to \infty } \frac{1}{N} \sum\limits_{n=1}^{N} z_{n} = 0
\end{align*}
In the proof, it directly states that given any $\epsilon$ and $D \in \mathbb{N}$ , we can always let $N$ be large enough, so we have
\begin{align*}
\left|  \frac{1}{N} \sum\limits_{n=1}^{N} z_{n} - \frac{1}{N} \frac{1}{D} \sum\limits_{n=1}^{N} \sum\limits_{d=1}^{D} z_{n+d} \right| < \epsilon
\end{align*}
I'm wondering why this is true.
I noticed that this can be simplified as
\begin{align*}
\left| \frac{1}{N} \sum\limits_{n=1}^{N} \left[ z_{n} - \frac{1}{D} \sum\limits_{d=1}^{D} z_{n+d} \right] \right|  < \epsilon
\end{align*}
This indicates that this has something to do with the arithmetic mean of the sequence. I also tried to use Abel's summation by parts, but it seems it doesn't work.
I got pretty stuck here. Any help? Thanks!

Here an alternative proof.

(Van Der Corput inequality) Let $(z_n:n\in\mathbb{N})\subset \mathbb{C}$. For any $1\leq H\leq N$,
\begin{align}
\Big|\sum^N_{n=1}z_n\Big|\leq (N+H-1)^{1/2}\left(H\sum^N_{n=1}|z_n|^2+ 2\sum^{H-1}_{h=1}(H-h)\sum^{N-h}_{n=1}{\frak R}\big(z_n\overline{z_{n+h}}\big)\right)^{1/2}\tag{1}\label{one}
\end{align}

A proof of this inequality can be found here.
If $|z_n|\leq B$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, from \eqref{one} it follows that
\begin{align}
\Big|\frac1N\sum^N_{n=1}z_n\Big|^2&\leq \frac{N+H-1}{NH}\left(\frac1N\sum^N_{n=1}|z_n|^2\,+\,2\sum^{H-1}_{h=1}\frac{H-h}{H}\frac{N-h}{N}\frac1{N-h}\sum^{N-h}_{n=1}{\frak R}(z_n\overline{z_{n+h}})\right)\\
&\leq \frac{N+H-1}{NH}B + 2{\frak R}\left(\sum^{H-1}_{h=1}\frac{(H-h)(N-h)(N+H-1)}{N^2H^2}\frac{1}{N-h}\sum^{N-h}_{n=1}z_nz_{n+h}\right)
\end{align}
Letting $N\rightarrow\infty$ yields
$$\limsup_N\Big|\frac1N\sum^N_{n=1}z_n\Big|^2\leq \frac{B}{H} + 2{\frak R}\left(\sum^{H-1}_{h=1}(H-h)\lim_N\frac{(N-h)(N+H-1)}{N^2H^2}\frac{1}{N-h}\sum^{N-h}_{n=1}z_nz_{n+h}\right)=\frac{B}{H}$$
As $H$ is arbitrary, $\lim_N\frac1N\sum^N_{n=1}z_n=0$.

Note that collecting terms according to the value of $m+d$ reveals that
\begin{align*}
\sum_{m=1}^{N} \sum\limits_{d=1}^{D} z_{m+d} =
\sum_{n=2}^D (n-1)z_n + D\sum_{n=D+1}^{N} z_n + \sum_{n=N+1}^{N+D} (N+D+1-n)z_n,
\end{align*}
and so
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N} z_{n} - \frac{1}{D} \sum\limits_{n=1}^{N} \sum\limits_{d=1}^{D} z_{n+d} = \sum_{n=2}^D \biggl( 1 - \frac{n-1}D \biggr) z_n - \sum_{n=N+1}^{N+D} \biggl( \frac{N+D+1-n}D \biggr) z_n \ll D
\end{align*}
since the $z_n$ are bounded and the coefficients in parentheses are all at most $1$. The indicated inequality follows as soon as $N$ is a large constant multiple of $D/\varepsilon$.

Where did you use the condition $$\lim\limits_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^{N} z_{n+d} \overline{z_{n}} =0?$$

It seems that that condition isn't needed for this particular step of the proof.
